# Selction API not available Angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Im using Angular ui-grid v3.2.9. I simply cannot get access to the selection API. My jade template is:

```
.portfolio-grid(ng-if='!portfolioListComponentVM.refreshing', ui-grid='portfolioListComponentVM.gridOptions',
    ui-grid-selection, ui-grid-pagination, ui-grid-auto-resize)
```

And the javascript:

```
    this.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = (gridApi) => {

        this.gridApi = gridApi;

        this.gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged(this.$scope, this._paginationHandler.bind(this));

        this.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged(this.$scope,function(rows){
            console.log('in rowSelectionChanged');
        });
```

Note that I have `ui-grid-selection` and `ui-grid-pagination` directives in the jade template (and I see these when I view source in the browser). However, I always get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

This is for the line:

```
this.gridApi.selection.on
```

The pagination works fine. I can see that gridApi simply is not giving access to the selection API. When I log this.gridApi I see:

```
core: Object
grid: Grid
listeners: Array[1]
pagination: Object
```

'selection' is not there, despite me including the directive. [In all the documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection), there is a `gridApi.selection` API. But somehow not for me.

What could possibly be going on?

Comment: Do you have the "ui.grid.selection" module included in your Angular modules?

Comment: Nope, that was the problem!